# stuck in "Error: number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)"

Tags: r

[image: the problem]

its a school assignment and I have no idea how to solve this, I've looked at tutorials and none of them seems to explain how to solve problems like these.

```r
no_1.labels = no_1$Product
table(no_1.labels)
no_1.data <- no_1[2:3]

no_1.scale <- scale(no_1.data)
no_1.data <- dist(no_1.scale)

fviz_nbclust(no_1.scale, kmeans, method = "wss")`
```

I've only got this far before I got stuck, did I do something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags. Side note: RStudio is an IDE capable of running multiple languages, e.g. R and Python.

Comment: Hi! you are using the function `fviz_nbclust` which is meant to help determining the optimal number of clusters. In your case, the number of clusters is already given in the assignment (k = 3). Look into `?kmeans` which is the function you need and note that `dist` defaults to eucliedan distance but you need manhattan distance.

Comment: Also, try to provide an example easy to copy-and-paste into others' environment.